# How recent should my bank statement be when applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, bulgaria

I will apply for a Bulgarian visa on July 8th, but my bank statement is from November 17th to May 17th, is that maybe a problem for them ? Could that cause a refusal or will they just ask for a more recent statement ? I don't want to include it after that date because my balance wasn't good enough after May 17th, please any one have any info for bank statement how it should look like ? What will the consequences be if it's earlier ?

Comment: What do you mean by 17-11 and 17-5 ? November 17th and May 17th ?

Comment: Where did you see the requirement for bank statements ? I was browsing their list of requirements and didn't come across it

Comment: @Blackbird57 me too , it may be different from country to other , so asked to know , if it may cause any problem in general ??

Comment: Depending on your previous queries, I would say make a watertight case for your visa. You have been refused visas earlier, so too many refusals will make you getting a visa much more difficult.

Comment: @DumbCoder where does it say he's been refused visas ?

Comment: [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/bank-balance-for-getting-a-schengen-visa) could help. They're not asking for bank statements, but rather for proof of enough means to support yourself

Comment: @Blackbird57 i think he check my previous topics but i want to know now , in general for any embassy if the statement bit earlier like that it may cause any problem ?

Comment: November is a bit old, but May is fairly recent. I personally can't say, it's entirely up to them.

Comment: @Blackbird57 i think it's about belguim

Comment: @GayotFow I think an imprecise answer is okay. In case Bulgaria updates updates their guidelines we could add a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are applying for a short-term visa and you have determined that the most recent bank statements do not present your financial standing as favourably as older bank statements.  You contemplate submitting just the older bank statements and now ask if that strategy has unacceptably high risk.

The technical name for that strategy is '[*prevaricating*](http://onelook.com/?w=prevaricating&ls=a)'.

They do not like it and if they suspect that you are prevaricating your credibility will be  damaged. Additionally you will get a [refusal on reason #8](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) (or its equivalent) which is bad and matters will be worse because damaged credibility carries over from one application to the next.  Financial standing, on the other hand, does not.

An alternative strategy is [transparency](http://onelook.com/?w=transparency&ls=a&loc=home_ac_transparanc). This is defined as an `honest way of doing things that allows other people to know exactly what you are doing`.

To use this alternative you would assemble the necessary documents without regard to how they make you look.  If you think your recent bank statement paint a bad picture, you can use word crafting and composition skills to explain it away.  To get started you can write something like...

> My bank statements for May show that the balances are lower than
>   previous months.  This should be treated as an extraordinary variance
>   because multiple one-off events occurred simultaneously.  The most
>   damaging event was blah blah blah; and secondarily the account was
>   nearly depleted by blah blah blah. Note that all of these events were
>   handled from my existing reserves without creating indebtedness. As mentioned previously these were one-off events with no likelihood of repeating; I expect the
>   accounts to be fully restored to their normal state in July and blah
>   blah blah blah.

It goes without saying that your explanation should be relentlessly honest.  They love that sort of thing; they eat it up... especially if the English usage is polished and constrained to factual evidence (i.e., nobody wants to go through a long-winded, needlessly complex explanation).  And oh! Avoid using my exact words!

There are no silver bullets in a short-term visa application; You can still get refused because your finances may not be that healthy. But the refusal reason will be `you have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence...` (or its equivalent) and your credibility will be intact. It means they will be more likely to believe you in future applications.

Prevarication versus transparency. Both strategies can lead to refusals, but only one assures that you don't get a credibility hit.