# Can I be in transit in Athens for 24 h without transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, bulgaria

I am Egyptian and I just have Bulgarian visa. My flight will have transit in Athens for 20 h, will it be a problem to stay in the airport without Schengen visa?

Comment: I removed your question about Skyscanner, which was very unclear and unrelated to the other question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Also, it seems you finally obtained a Bulgarian visa, so you could perhaps answer [your own question about this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/bank-statement-required-for-bulgarian-visa) to let future readers know how it went.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) Egyptian citizens do not need an *airport transit visa* anywhere in the Schengen area except in the Czech Republic. So if your route allows sterile transit, you would not need a visa.

I could not find any definite information about Athens but the airport does not close at night so overnight transit should be possible. While I am not able to cite any explicit rule, I think that 24 hours is usually the threshold, if only because it's often necessary to collect your luggage for longer transit, which also implies leaving the transit lounge of the airport.

If you need to leave the airport for any reason, you would need a visa.

Comment: I didn't understand u for all , but anyway I won't leave the airport for any reason but I will change the plane , is that will cause problem !