# Is it required to be 6 months for the bank statement to obtain visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, schengen-visas

If I want to obtain a visa to visit Europe (Balkan Area) or for my work, they ask for a bank statement up to 6 months.

I am currently newly employed, my bank account will get a decent monthly salary payment which is enough to "take care of myself" in my trip outside.

Do I need to have consecutive 6 months to be accepted for a visa?

I am speaking of Tourist/Type C

Comment: Related question [How recent should my bank statement be when applying for a Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/how-recent-should-my-bank-statement-be-when-applying-for-a-schengen-visa), [Minimum balance fir Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/what-is-the-minimum-bank-balance-for-getting-a-schengen-visa) and [What do bank statements say about me](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) (for UK, but its principles are generally applicable)

Comment: Is your bank account new or only your job?

Comment: @Willeke personal account that is not new, but will make a new one in the job's salary currency

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the officer who is going to review your case: you just got a job, and now you want to go on holiday. Wouldn’t that seem weird to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have bank statements of your old and new accounts, covering the last 6 months. If you had both accounts at the same time have statements for both.

Those officers do not just want to know how much money you have currently but even more what pattern of income and expenses you have.

Having a new job and with that a new income is good, but if that is all you show they will not trust you. Showing that you had a life, and a bank account, before the new job will explain a lot, even if your income then would not have been enough for your current travel plans.